# Using PHP Namespace for class yet receiving error of usage

Tags: php

I am receiving the error: `Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Services\EncryptionService' not found`.

- class is in `<root>\services\EncryptionService.php`
- class has on first row `namespace Services;`
- PHP file calling class in `<root>\db\db_change_password.php`
- PHP file calling class has on first row `use Services\EncryptionService;`

usage:

```
$encryption_service = new EncryptionService;
$encryptedPassword = $encryption_service->encrypt($password);
```

And provides fatal error.

> EDIT:

- autoload_classmap.php
- autoload_files.php
- autoload_namespaces.php
- autoload_psr4.php
- autoload_real.php
  autoload_static.php

Comment: What does your autoloader look like?

Comment: Yes, you need to show us your composer.json file if you have one

Comment: Be aware of the capital letters "Services".

Comment: I've been hired to treat code that is old, in terms of it's syntax and usage, they haven't heard about composer, in anycase, I have installed composer with diff. packages in vendor, but there is no root autoloader other than composer.

Comment: I can't tell if you're saying you are using an autoloader or not then (is the composer autoloader loaded in the app?). If you don't have one, you need to require the relevant files into the script, PHP won't auto include files / classes on its own.

Comment: Try define it as `\Services\EncryptionService` incase the namespace is causing it to think its `\Foo\Bar\Services\EncryptionService`

Comment: Everyone and @Jonnix: edited and included the autoloader files in I have in vendor/composer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should use autoload class to load any class you use if you don't and you use namespace create folder put this code at the file on the folder you create then include it or require at index and APP_PATH const for the path of the project I hope this helps you

```
<?php


  namespace Services\lib;

  class Autoload
  {
    public static function autoload($className){
    //remove the main namespace
    $className=str_replace("Services","",$className);

    $className=str_replace("\\","/",$className);
    $className=$className.".php";
    $className=strtolower($className);
    //echo $className;
    if(file_exists(APP_PATH.$className)){
        require_once (APP_PATH.$className);
    }

  }

  }

spl_autoload_register(__NAMESPACE__.'\Autoload::autoload');
```